# RactJS: Child-to-parent Component communication

Tags: reactjs, parent-child

I have a Child component - `ExportModalMultiRoom.js` where users can select multiple rooms. This is saved in an array - `selectedRooms` which I need to send to Parent -`ExportModal.js` and setState of `roomIdNo: []` with the value of `selectedRooms`. So far I've tried to pass a function to the child through props.

```
Parent - `ExportModal.js`

export default class ExportModal extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            roomIdNo: [],

        };
        this.setStateFromChild = this.setStateFromChild.bind(this);
    }


setStateFromChild(selectedRooms){
        this.setState({roomIdNo: selectedRooms});
    }

  render() {
     return() {
    <ExportReportRoomSelectionModal setStateFromChild={this.setStateFromChild}/>
  }
}
```

The child then calls `submitProps` function and passes value of `selectedRooms` array that the parent is supposed to setState to `roomId`.

```
Child - ` ExportModalMultiRoom `

export default class ExportReportRoomSelectionModal extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);


        this.state = {
            rooms: roomOrder,
            selectedRooms: []
        };

        this.onSelectRooms = this.onSelectRooms.bind(this);
        this.submitProps = this.submitProps.bind(this);
    }


   submitProps(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        const { selectedRooms } = this.state; 
        const { setStateFromChild } = this.props;

        setStateFromChild(selectedRooms);
    }

render() {
     return() {

           <form>
                <Modal>
                        <Modal.Title>Print PDF</Modal.Title>
                    =
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <p>Please selected the rooms</p>

                        <Grid> 
                            <Row className="show-grid">
                                { this.state.rooms.map((roomName, i ) => 

                                    <Col key={i}>
                                        <Panel}>  
                                            <Panel.Heading onClick={this.onSelectRooms} id={roomName}> 
                                                {roomName}                               
                                            </Panel.Heading>
                                        </Panel> 
                                    </Col>
                                )}
                            </Row>
                        </Grid>

                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button
                            onClick={this.props.handleHide}
                            data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#export-modal"
                            onSubmit={this.submitProps}
                        >
                            Send PDF
                        </Button>
                        <Button onClick={this.props.handleHide}>Close</Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>

                </Modal>
            </form>
    }
}
```

Problem is in the ExportModal - Parent `roomIdNo: []` is empty because selectedRoom is empty too I believe. As soon as I type something on the form in ExportModal.js the console log prints roomIdNo state is empty

Comment: In parent component add: `constructor(props) {super(props); this. setStateFromChild.bind(this);}`

Comment: Hi LiJonas I have them, perhaps i'll show you all the code for the parent. thanks

Comment: you should set your state in the parent, including selectedRooms. Why would you want to set it in the child component to pass it to the parent?

Comment: Hi gianni, the child component gets rendered first where user clicks on multiple rooms that is saved in an array. Then the parent will need that array to make a post request, if that make sense. If this approach is wrong may be i should try including selectedRooms in parent.

Comment: you should set selectedRooms in the parent, and you can pass it down as a prop to the child component if it\s needed there. The function to update the parent state should also be passed down as a prop. Passing the parent state as props would cause the child to re render as soon as the parent state changes.

Comment: so say if I have my `ExportReportModalMultirooms.js` as parent that passes the selectedRooms Array as props to `ExportModal.js`. How do i set the props array on state`roomIdNo` of `ExportModal.js`?